# Angular redirect to module

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a module called page with its own routing.
In my root app.routing.module I redirect to the page module. and in the page module I have a page.routing.module file and I want to redirect to a component and that's where I can't do it.

I don't see my error.

**app.routing.module** // Project Root file

```
const routes: Route: [

{ path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'page' },
{ path: 'page', loadChildren: () => import('page/page.module').then(m => m.PageModule )

]
```

It works, I am redirected to the page.

**page.routing.module**

```
const routes: Route: [

{ path: '', component: PageComponent },

]
```

**page**

```
page
 - page.component.html
 - page.component.css
 - page.component.spec.ts
 - page.routing.module.ts
 - page.module.ts
```

I want to display PageCompoent

Comment: Your code looks fine... what exactly happens? Any errors in your console? Do you have your lazy loaded routing file (page.routing) correctly registered as a forChild? Do you have a router outlet in your main app? Not enough information here I'm afraid.

Comment: Is there any code written in PageComponent file? You can check by putting a console.log in the constructor or ngOnInit of page.component.ts file. Is it's html file(page.component.html) blank?

Comment: nop is empty for the moment only h1 tag in html component

Answer (score 0):

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

please try to change the page.routing.module forRoot to forChild